# subquery scoring and coord in edismax ranking in SOLR

Tags: solr

I am using edismax ranking in solr 4.1. I have a queryparser which generates a few sub queries given a single query string. As I was looking at the specific ranking detail (by adding "debugQuery=on"), I found the followings:

1> It looks like rank scores of all sub queries are added first
2> And then there is a multiplication of this total score and coord factor. It looks like coord factor is the ratio of how many sub queries got match. For example, if a query turns into 3 sub queries and if only 1 of them gets hit, then coord factor would be 1/3.

I am wondering 1> whether my observation is correct. 2> if so, whether there is a way to change these behaviour something like the followings:

1> Instead of summing the scores of sub queries, just take the max score.
2> Ignore coord factor.

If current solr 4.1 implementation doesn't support, any pointer which source code to change or use as a reference would be great.

Answer (score 3):

Check for the params which control the behaviour :-

[Tie Breaker](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#tie_.28Tie_breaker.29) -

> A value of "0.0" makes the query a pure "disjunction max query" --
>   only the maximum scoring sub query contributes to the final score. A
>   value of "1.0" makes the query a pure "disjunction sum query" where it
>   doesn't matter what the maximum scoring sub query is, the final score
>   is the sum of the sub scores. Typically a low value (ie: 0.1) is
>   useful.

[Coord](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#mm_.28Minimum_.27Should.27_Match.29) -

> In Solr 1.4 and prior, you should basically set mm=0 if you want the
>   equivilent of q.op=OR, and mm=100% if you want the equivilent of
>   q.op=AND. In 3.x and trunk the default value of mm is dictated by the
>   q.op param (q.op=AND => mm=100%; q.op=OR => mm=0%). Keep in mind the
>   default operator is effected by your schema.xml  entry. In older versions of Solr the default
>   value is 100% (all clauses must match)

Remove the mm factor to remove the coord calculation and set the tie to 0 to consider the maximum of the score.